# Running some code right after parsley in submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, parsley.js, jquery-events

I am working with a third party project that uses html-instantiated parsley for input validation. I would like to run some additional server-side validation before submitting for real, so I tried registering an event handler in the `onclick` attribute of the submit button.

Now my problem is that its behavior is not consistent when reloading the page...

Right now it's supposed to run before parsley if I click submit my handler will run but some times only parsley will run.

Is there a more supported way to run an event handler (with the possibility of cancelling the event) when a form would normally submit because it's valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this properly is to add a custom validator which will return a promise. You have some [examples here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/ajax.html). With the right priority, your check would run only after all the other (non asynchroneous) validations have succeeded.

Comment: Is there a way to use `await` within the `theForm.parsley().on('form:submit',handler);` event? Also is it possible to run the validation logic only if everything else is valid? I ended up using `form:submit` to do the check but then I had to get the return value from an ajax call so i tried `await` but it wouldn't work...